# `useState` erroneously links multiple instances of a single Redux + React Native Component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

**Context**

I've created a custom React Native Text component that I call `TextInputSetting`, which should update the redux state as a user enters text into it.

The component works fine if I use it just once, but as soon as I try to reuse it, I run into problems (see GIF below to see what I mean).

In experimenting, I found that if I duplicate the component definition (i.e. create `TextInputSetting2`), I run into the same problem. However, if I duplicate the component *and* use different variables names for the results of the call to `useState` (i.e. `tempText2` & `setTempText2` in one component definition and `tempText` & `setTempText` in the other), only then the component instances will function as expected.

**Question**

Why can't I invoke `useState` in a reusable React Native + Redux component, and have it work as expected?

**Details**

[image]

`TextInputSetting.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, View } from "react-native";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { updateSetting } from "./actions";

export const TextInputSetting = (props) => {
  const settings = useSelector((state) => state.settingsReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  [tempText, setTempText] = useState(settings[props.settingKey]);

  return (
    <View style={[{ paddingLeft: 50, marginTop: 5, flexDirection: "row" }]}>
      <Text>{props.label}:</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={tempText}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "yellow",
          borderWidth: 1,
          width: props.boxWidth,
          textAlign: "center",
        }}
        onChangeText={(text) => setTempText(text)}
        onEndEditing={() => dispatch(updateSetting(props.settingKey, tempText))}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

`actions.js`

```
export const UPDATE_STATE = "UPDATE_STATE";

export const updateSetting = (k, v) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_STATE,
    payload: { key: k, value: v },
  });
};
```

`reducers.js`

```
import { UPDATE_STATE } from "./actions";

const defaultSettings = {
  set1: "default1",
  set2: "default2",
};

export const settingsReducer = (state = defaultSettings, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_STATE:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.key]: action.payload.value };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistor, store } from "./store";
import { TextInputSetting } from "./TextInputSetting";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 50, textAlign: "center", paddingTop: 200 }}>
            Hi there
          </Text>
          <TextInputSetting
            label="First Field"
            settingKey="set1"
            boxWidth={200}
          />
          <TextInputSetting
            label="Second Field"
            settingKey="set2"
            boxWidth={200}
          />
        </>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

**Code**

You can run the code for yourself; I've zipped the full example here (less than 1 MB): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FJ5AGXlT680uvHIjKxaZUEwliW79_MmT/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on this line.

```
[tempText, setTempText] = useState(settings[props.settingKey]);
```

It should be

```
const [tempText, setTempText] = useState(settings[props.settingKey]);
```

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/ey5sabd5S)